# Yii2[base] не может найти класс находящийся в пространстве имён

Tags: php, yii2, классы, виджет, namespace

Существует класс `MyClass`, который находится в пространстве имён

> namespace yii\base\widgets;

В представлении пытаясь обратиться к этому классу, прописав в use'ах

> use yii\base\widgets\MyClass;

Фреймворк кидает исключение:

> Class 'yii\base\widgets\MyClass' not found

Где ошибка? Может что-то не так с пространством имён?

Comment: Какой физический путь к файлу?

Comment: главная папка\compontnts\widgets\MyClass.php

Comment: зайдите в папку эту и выполните команду `pwd`

Comment: Почитайте про psr-4, вы неверно указали namespace

Comment: виджет должен быть в папке `widgets`, которая в корне проекта, а не в `components`..... а если вы делаете компонент, то и неймспейс должны задавать в представлении соответствующий `use \app\components\MyClass;` или что-то подобное... То есть, скорее вы просто не туда виджет положили.. не  в ту папку

Comment: `use compontnts\widgets\MyClass.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пространство имен `yii\*` находиться в папке `vendor\yiisoft`.

Для вашего файла `главная папка\compontnts\widgets\MyClass.php` (исходя из комментариев), пространство имен класса должно иметь вид `app\compontnts\widgets`, а для его использования в представлении необходимо прописать

```
 use app\compontnts\widgets\MyClass
```

Comment: В самом классе нужно не забыть namespace поменять на app\compontnts\widgets